# connection to db4free with C programming

Tags: c, linux, database, openwrt

I'am working on a project and i wanted to know how can i connect to my database in **db4free.net** from **C** .

I have a router which is having **openWRT** Operating System and is **Linux** based. I want a write a **C** program for my router to get my data in db4free.net into the router and display it on the end device.

Please let me know if this is possible using C.If yes then pls let me know how to go about it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to provide information about how the data is available to you on db4free. Obviously, it is mysql, but do you get a .sql file, a bzipped compressed .sql file -- what? Second, you will need to know how to compile applications for your router? Yes, it is Linux based, but what is the architecture, machine type, etc.. You can't just compile the application for your x86_64 box and expect it to run on your router. As long as you have access to your data at db4free, you can write an application in C to access that data and display it. But it is not a trivial "Hello World" type deal.

Comment: I want to get data from db4free.net into a router n then dipplay it on LCD display device.

Firstly, I wanted to fetch data in character stream, as we want to display in LCD device so only character display is possible.

I dont know whether Compressed or sql file will work .

Second, To compile application i am referring the following attached tutorial.

[link] (http://manoftoday.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/writing-and-compiling-a-simple-program-for-openwrt/)

I am new to this Topic so i dont know exactly where to start so pls let me know if i m missing something.

Thank You.

Comment: The reason the connection makes the difference is that will dictate what method you use in C to get the information from db4free. By your response, it appears you intend to establish a connection over http and then retrieve results back as an answer to some sort of query. You will have to work within the confines of the openWRT SDK which will allow you to compile your code to run on the router. As far as a place to start - finish the example in the link you provided and make sure you can actually compile/run the "hello world" example on your router, then dig in to how to get the database info

Comment: Can Socket programming be implemented.
Simaiar to the "Hello World" program if we write a C socket program for our router which will fetch data from db4free.net.

Comment: Yes, you can connect to db4free using TCP to port 80 (just like a browser) and establish a network connection which will allow you to receive the data. Depending on what db4free requires, you will need to provide whatever credentials are needed to reach your account.